# Why do System.Text.Encodings.Web.UrlEncoder.Default.Encode and System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode produce different results for semicolons?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Why do these two methods produce different results for a semicolon?

```cs
System.Text.Encodings.Web.UrlEncoder.Default.Encode(";")
// output: ";"

System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(";")
// output: "%3b"
```

The documentation gives no explanation:

- [UrlEncoder.Default.Encode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encodings.web.urlencoder)
- [HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.urlencode)

According to the rfc ";" is a reserved character and should be encoded. So expected would be a %3b for both methods.